# mutltiple HX711 with mcp23017 expansion board

Tags: pigpio, bit-bang

I try to set up multiple HX711 weight sensors on a raspberry PI with a MCP23017 expansion Board (baud rate 100kbps). The problem is that the HX711 sensor switches off when its input (pd_sck) is set high for more than 60 µs. The way to read data from the HX711 sensor is to bitbang 24 bits on the pd_sck and read after every pulse one bit from the output of the sensor. The MCP23017 causes a delay so that the pd_sck pin is set high for more than 60 µs (that apparently does not happen without the expansion board).

I tried to use smbus to read from the bus and send the high/low signal in one block:

```
block_data = [
                1 << self._pd_sck,  # set pd_sck high
                0                   # set pd_sck low
            ]
self.bus.write_block_data(self.device_adress, OLATB, block_data)
```

This does not seem to work. I read it might be possible pigpio using bitbang i2c interface. I cannot figure out the transaction sequence and how to set a delay though. I think it should look something like this:

```
pi = pigpio.pi()
pi.i2c_write_byte_data(handler, IODIRA, 0xFF)  # A is inputs 
pi.i2c_write_byte_data(handler, IODIRB, 0x00)  # B is outputs

h = pi.bb_i2c_open(4, 5, 100000)

count, data = pi.bb_i2c_zip(h,
        [4, 0x27, 
         7, 0b11111111,  # set all high            
         7, 0])  # set all low
```

I am sure that the concatenated operations of pi.bb_i2c_zip are not correct. Can someone help me how to use these operators to set a the pd_sck pin for less than 60 µs high and then read from the doub pin and repeat this 24 times.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Bit bang I2C via pigpio will be subject to all the Linux jitter.  You will be better off using the kernel driver.  If the kernel driver doesn't work neither will a bit bang approach.

Comment: This might help: MCP23017 IO Expander (IOX) controlling DHT22 Temperature and Humidity Sensor (THS) - rpi.org.forum 2018aug07 Viewed 3175 times
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1350085&hilit=mcp23017+am2302#p1350085.

Comment: This might also help: 
Searched query: hx711 tlfong01: Search found 62 matches: hx711 tlfong01, 2021mar07
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=hx711+tlfong01